# R get the cost function value from Predict

Tags: r, bayesian

Say you created a `naiveBayes` model in R, and clearly, you can see all the conditional probabilities that are necessary to make the prediction for any given input.

However, after I use `predict` to make a prediction based on some test data. How can I get the cost function (maximized likelihood in this case) after the prediction? What is the cost function for y=level1 / level2 ...?

Can I simply get that from the predict function? or I have to manually calculate it myself doing something like:

```
P <- P(x1|y=level1) * P(x2|y=level1) ... P(xd|y=level1) * P(y=level1) / (Px1 * x2 .. xd)
```